# What are some resources on belief dissemination?

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy, belief

In the social psychology literature, there is a lot of discussion about the pathways through which one achieves social belief formation (i.e. persuasion, coercion, etc.). These differ from those provided in the philosophy literature (i.e. imitation, contagion, etc.). And, the literature on social doxology is sparse.

Aside from the declining interest in memetics, there does not seem to be a robust body of contemporary literature on the social pathways through which beliefs (as opposed to memes) are transmitted.

Could someone point me in the right direction on where to look. I am new to this research area and might be missing something.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the Social Ontology literature. I've seen some hints towards your topic of interest there. For a historical approach, you're looking at Hegel and Kierkegaard which might not be worth the effort to understand depending on the goals / size / level of your project.

Comment: How are beliefs different from memes?

Comment: Hi, you tagged history-of-philosophy; are you only interested in 'contemporary literature'?

Answer (score 1):

Try the book *Liars and Outliers: Enabling the Trust Society Needs to Thrive* by Bruce Schneier it has a very extensive list of references and notes (many not included in the book) at the end of the book that I think would be relevant.